# In various programs, window greys up/going nowhere (frozen/locked)

Tags: 16.04, networking, process, cifs

This is happening in various programs, often LibreOffice, but this example is gedit.

I launched it from a right click in Dolphin (if it had run up it would have been a second instance). Second instance pops into side bar for a few seconds then it's gone. Now the first instance is unusable and greyed off.  This happens four or five times a day and is making 16.04 un-usable.  14.04 seemed better.  I have known it come back, maybe half hour later, but how do I find out what it's blocked on?  Nothing useful in `dmesg` and none of the files in `/var/log` have recent enough times to be relevant.  I can see it in `ps -AF --forest` but if I `gdb` & `at <pid>`, `gdb` stops there so I can tell nothing from that.

Bit more info, right now the stuck program is filezilla. Adding a few more columns in System Monitor, specifically 'Waiting Channel' and I can see FileZilla is showing `cifs_reconnect_tcon` whereas no other programs are. Don't know what that means but I'm beginning to think this is to do with `/etc/fstab` mounting a couple of drives on a Windows 2003 server on the LAN. Could that be part of the problem? What can I do to get my Ubuntu going again, without rebooting or is there some other way around this?

3.8 GiB / Intel® Core™ i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 8 / Intel® HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2) / 121.8 GB HDD / 16.06

I have four instances of FireFox with half a dozen tabs in each plus 3 or 4 other apps going.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was CIFS.  We had an old Windows 2003 server which we mounted with `/etc/fstab`.  When it decided not to respond (or the LAN maybe) then app was locked and greyed off and the only clue came from turning on all of the columns in System Montior.

Now that server has been moved to Ubuntu - problem disappears!  So glad - this was a right pain and impossible to locate.  Hope this helps somebody, basically don't use CIFS in fstab to a Windows 2003 Server, unless you like rebooting.